# Data channel in Edge Browser

Tags: microsoft-edge

Could someone help me with the following - is Data Channel supported by Edge browser? I can't find this with Edge while with all other browsers it is ok. I want to ensure data transfer (chat) directly browser to browser.

I would appreciate if someone could provide me with some guidance for this case.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. This site is only for asking questions regarding development. please ask other types of questions on their special ones.

Comment: Hi Ashkan, thanks for your reply. I wanted to know if data channel for Edge is supported for browser to browser chat or is projected to be development anytime in the near future. Otherwise, please help me understand where is the best venue to pose this question concerning this specific feature.  Madlen

Answer (score 1):

WebRTC Data Channel support is currently [under review](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/8118837-support-webrtc-datachannels-in-workers) for MS Edge. It's been that way for a while however with the recent announcement of WebRTC support in Safari 11 (including [Data Channels](https://twitter.com/jonathandavis/status/871857711910080512)) I suspect that this will spur MS to prioritize it in Edge.